# Python "Memory Error." / Saving Memory

Tags: python, performance, memory

I've made a program that takes a list of numbers and outputs the "triples."
A triple is represented by x/y/z and x>=y>=z

For some reason, when executing my code, I'm getting a "memory error." I'm not sure why this is happening or how to solve it. I can only assume that it has something to do with managing memory incorrectly or making my program more efficiently.

This is lengthy, but I can't leave anything out because I have no Idea what the problem is.

So two questions... How do I fix this "memory error." And how can I make this program more efficient? (It's terribly slow as is.)

Program Output:
[[6, 3, 1], [6, 2, 2], [6, 2, 1], [6, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
11

```
l = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]

def answer(l):
    l.sort()
    l.reverse()
    triples = []
    final = []
    for first_main_counter in range(len(l)):
        main_testing_number = l[first_main_counter]
        divisors = []
        divisors = [x for x in l if main_testing_number % x == 0]
        del divisors[0]
        for second_main_counter in range(len(divisors)):
            second_main_testing_number = divisors[second_main_counter]
            divisors2 = []
            divisors2 = [x for x in divisors if second_main_testing_number % x == 0]
            del divisors2[0]
            for x in range(len(divisors2)):
                triples.append([l[first_main_counter],divisors[second_main_counter],divisors2[x]])

    seen = set()
    for item in triples:
        t = tuple(item)
        if t not in seen:
            final.append(item)
            seen.add(t)
    print(final)
    print(len(final))


answer(l)
```

Comment: How long is the list?

Comment: What does `x/y/z` mean?  From your code I'm guessing you intend `/` to mean "divides".  Also, you wrote `z>=y>=z`.  Did you mean `z>=y>=x`?

Comment: `%%time` --> `Wall time: 572 µs`

Comment: You should show the output you expect for your sample input.

Comment: list is anywhere from 1 to 2000 elements

Comment: i put the output in the question.. if my list is [1,2,3,4,5,6] the triples would be [1,2,4] [1,2,6] [1,3,6]

Comment: You still didn't respond to my earlier comment.  What does `x/y/z` mean?  It is not possible for x to be a divisor of y if `x>y`.

Comment: oh im sorry. yes I meant z>=y>=x. And yes, it means "divides"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do that much, much more simply:

```
>>> {(x, y, z) for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(l, 3) if z % y == 0 and y % x == 0}
 {(1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 1, 5),
 (1, 1, 6),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 6),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 2, 6)}
```

That's it.  As long as your list is sorted, `itertools.combinations` will only return triples in ascending order.  (If your list isn't sorted, just sort it first.  If you want them in the other order, reverse-sort it and switch the direction of the divisibility checks.)  You don't need to do all the laborious divisor checking you're doing.  Just check every combination and see if it satisifies "x divides y" and "y divides z".

If you care more about speed, here is a version that is comparable in speed to your original, but much more readable:

```
def anotherWay(stuff):
    result = set()
    for ix, x in enumerate(stuff):
        for iy, y in enumerate(stuff[ix+1:], ix+1):
            if y % x:
                continue
            for z in stuff[iy+1:]:
                if z % y:
                    continue
                result.add((x, y, z))
    return result
```

(This again assumes the list is in *ascending* order, and returns results where `z >= y >= x`, which is what you asked for in your question, but not what your code actually does.)

Comment: Wow. That's a ton easier than what I did lol. I'm also assuming the execution time is better as well? Would this solve my memory problem?

Comment: @Will: Try it and see.  If your list grows large, it may well take a long time, since the number of possible combinations grows explosively.  But it shouldn't use too much memory, since `itertools.combinations` will only generate one combination at a time and not hold them all in memory at once.

Comment: Ok thank you! And one last thing! How would I then count how many triples it outputs? I feel silly for asking this

Comment: @Will: The result is a set.  If you assign the result to a variable (with `triples = {...}`) you can just do `len(triples)` to see how many there are.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: With a list containing number 1 through 500 my program took 0.2 seconds to complete while this one-liner took 4.4 seconds. So this isn't going to work :(

Comment: @Will: I added an alternative version which is faster, although still maybe not as fast as your original.  But your original question wasn't about speed, it was about memory.  If you have specific requirements for memory usage and speed you need to specify those, as well as specifying more about what kind of data you'll be running this on.  For many applications, taking 5 seconds instead of 0.2 is not important.  It may become important if it's taking 500 seconds instead of 20, but it won't do that on the kind of sample data you gave in your question.